# Does this matrix have a $2$-dimensional zero-eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Does the following matrix have a $2$-dimensional zero-eigenspace?
> $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} $$

---

I'm lost on what having "zero-eigenspace" means. Does it mean that zero is the eigenvalue they want me to look at the dimension of? Please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Probably you need to compute the dimension of the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $0$. Note that you can answer without any computation by looking at the trace of the matrix.

Comment: Yes, the $\lambda$-eigenspace of a matrix is the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda$. By definition the $0$-eigenspace is the kernel of the matrix (a far more common term).

Comment: @Lelouch could you elaborate on finding it by the trace? how does the trace relate to the dimension? thank you.

Comment: The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues counted with multiplicty, hence if it had a 2-dimensional "0-eigenspace", since we know that 1 is an eigevalue too (just look at the matrix) than the trace should be $0+0+1=1$ but here it's $1+1+1=3$.

Comment: Thank you! @Lelouch

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to me that the only thing it could mean is asking to compute the dimension of the eigenspace of the eigenvalue zero (i.e. the kernel) and say whether it is equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes more sense.